# reading inputstream of daemon process resulting program to stuck

Tags: java, inputstream

For testing purpose I need to start an daemon process from a command line and I need to read the output(Input Stream, Error Stream) of the process. When i tried to read the process output, it is getting stuck at bufferedReader.readLine()

```
    String command = "start server";
    String output = "";
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c");
    pb.directory(new File("C:\\tmp"));
    Process proc = null;
    try {
        proc = pb.start();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()));
        writer.write(command, 0, command.length());
        writer.newLine();
        writer.close();
        proc.waitFor(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            output = output + line + "\n";
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        while ((line = stdError.readLine()) != null)
            output = output + line + "\n";
        ByteArrayOutputStream opStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        opStream.writeTo(proc.getOutputStream());
        String stdOutput = new String(opStream.toByteArray());
        output = output + stdOutput;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while running command. " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (proc != null)
            proc.destroyForcibly();
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Can I use timeout for buffered reader so that program doesn't get stuck.
What is the best way to invoke daemon process and read its output?

Comment: *Unable to reproduce:* Since `cmd.exe /c` does nothing, returning immediately, the command sent is ignored and no output is generated, so Java code ends immediately without error, after printing 1 blank line.

Comment: *Curious:* What is the point of `opStream`? You create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then write the ***empty*** content to the process. What's the point? Of write nothing? Of writing to a process that has already completed? You then create a string from the still *empty* content of `opStream`. Again: Why?!?

Answer (score 0):

Standard java io is blocking. You might be able new io (nio) but that has other downsides (it is moew complex to use).

If you want to use java io, one way is to read the two streams from two separate threads. (You need to drain both streams separately, because there is a fixed size buffer for each of them. If one of these buffers fills up the whole process freezes until it is drain)

Something like:

```
private static class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {
    private final InputStream stream;

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream output;

    public StreamGobbler(InputStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            int read;
            while ((read = stream.read()) >= 0) {
                output.write(read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

{
    StreamGobbler stdin = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream());
    StreamGobbler stdout = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream());
    Executor executor = Exectors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    executor.submit(stdin);
    executor.submit(stdout);

    // do io for process
    // wait for process to finish
    // shutdown executorservice

    byte[] stdinBytes = stdin.output.toByteArray();
    byte[] stderrBytes = stderr.output.toByteArray();

}
```

Comment: Thank you K5_ for your suggestion. Can you also explain me how can I do the same using nio?